# Read select options / ng-options using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given a select element that I can add a directive to:

```
 <select ng-options="..." mydirective></select>
```

How can I, in my directive, access the ng-options as an object/array?  I would like to make a drop down alternative by reading the select and hiding/replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 for AngularJS is such a implementation, you could study that to find one approach on how to do it.

See source here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/blob/master/src/select2.js

What it does is search for the ng-options attribute on 'elem', get the name for the object on scope from the attribute and then set a $watch on that object to get the data. From there you can do basically do whatever you want.

ng-options requires the select element, so you cannot replace that and still use ng-options. That means you will have to add your directive as a attribute. Furthermore, it also means you have to consider the priority of your directive, depending on what you want to do with the data. Should it run before ng-options or after for instance?

Source for ng-options, which can be a useful study, can be found here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/6609e3da76dd898cfe85f75f23ab2e39fee65fe5/src/ng/directive/select.js#L4

All this considered, if you won't be using any of the functionality of 'select' or 'ng-options', they might end up being in the way (seeing as it creates a `<select>` element, and `<option>` children elements) . Creating your own 'my-options' directive could be a better approach.

Comment: Ya I am going back and forth with all the options and have looked at pretty much all. I would like to maintain the validation of forms so ideally would just like to have something that reads a select and hides it